# Getting my local repo ready to push to master

Tags: git

I'm trying to get my local repo in line with the master branch.

```
git status

On branch master
Your branch is behind 'central/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

And so i did pull

```
git pull 

    Updating 709446e..346e1ff
    Fast-forward  /test.ts | 5 ++---  1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Is my local repo in sync with the master? What is this fast forwarding git is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code you provide us, it seems your code is up to date.

Steps you can follow to check if your local branch is in order with your repo.

To check if your branch is in order to be pushed, you can do:

```
git status
```

There, you will see if it's up to date, behind or not. Also, If you want to check it better, you can do:

```
git log
```

And then, you can see if your last commit is the last commit in your master branch (You can see it in your repo).

Anyway, is a good practice to use other branches to work and let master only for your "clean version".
If you use a local branch, we can call it 'branch1', you can merge it with master with this steps:

```
git branch (to know you are in branch1)

git checkout master

git pull origin master

git merge branch1
```

You could have conflicts, so you should resolve before push. A simple tip for know what files are in conflict is to execute:

```
grep -Rl '<<< HEAD'
```

When there are not conflicts:

```
git push -u origin master
```

It's another way to work and it's more secure, because you (or your team) are not working on master.

Answer (score 0):

as you have pulled the remote central/master branch into your local master branch
the two branches have not diverged, there were just some new commits on central/master.
so your local master was fast-forwarded to origin/master without any merge.

Answer (score 0):

That's good.
Your branch seems to be up to date and there was no collision with the changes on the remote branch.
Fast-Forward means git just needed to move the pointer ahead.

You might want to look at the documentation section on [Basic Branching and Merging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

> You’ll notice the phrase “fast-forward” in that merge. Because the
>   commit C4 pointed to by the branch hotfix you merged in was directly
>   ahead of the commit C2 you’re on, Git simply moves the pointer
>   forward. To phrase that another way, when you try to merge one commit
>   with a commit that can be reached by following the first commit’s
>   history, Git simplifies things by moving the pointer forward because
>   there is no divergent work to merge together – this is called a
>   “fast-forward.”

Good luck.

Eyal